# Postfix - forwarding mail to an external email address

Tags: postfix, smtp, webmin

I'm not normally a Linux server guy: I'm a .NET programmer. However, I inherited a situation where there's a website hosted on a Linux server using Postfix on Webmin. They have several aliases set up, but none to external email addresses.

I tried setting one up as a test. I set up testing to forward test to validemailaddress@domain2.com. Then I sent an email from another email address to test@domain1.com and got the following back:

MailEnable: Message could not be delivered to some recipients.
The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

```
Recipient: [SMTP:test@domain1.com]
Reason: Remote SMTP Server Returned: 550 No Such User Here"
```

Now, if I change the address to "root", I don't get any messages back but I don't know where the email ends up; again, this is someone else's VPS and it's about as confusing as it gets. Is there a spot within Postfix on Webmin to allow for sending to external domains, and if so, where do I look for it? Thanks.

Comment: How did you setup the forward? Please share your configuration.

Comment: @EsaJokinen : I did it through Postfix on Webmin. If you want the fields, they're:

Description: (description of the alias)

Address: test

Enabled: Yes

Alias to: Email Address test@domain2.com

Comment: We don't deal with web hosting control panels on Server Fault. What's actually in the Postfix's configuration?